# Why stack community enter religion in her sites?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

Some people said, why stack community enter religion in her sites, for example this [hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) here :

> [Epiphany](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/epiphany) : La Befana vien di notte con le scarpe tutte rotte

People said, why  should I celibate with this [Epiphany (holiday)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(holiday))?

I think there are many religions here, there are **Christianity**, **Bábism**, **Islam**, **Judaism**, **Hinduism**, and and.

Comment: I want a hat for [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) as well.

Comment: @MarounMaroun but did we implicitly support the "United Church of Bacon" (yes that's a real thing) with "Mmmm Bacon"?

Comment: @MarcGravell Maybe it's time to suggest the baconbash, every year, for the whole year.

Comment: @MarcGravell not all people eat baconbash, so my question is not wrong, you just afraid to said the truth

Comment: @MrLY not all people use snapchat; not all people watch bugs bunny, star wars, top gun, the grinch, or the never ending story; not all people believe in yeti (ooh, I should check how many folks wear that on skeptics.se); none of these things are required; no hat is actively placed on you against your wishes; and you can disable the entire thing with a single click on "I hate hats".

Comment: mmm, don't be angry we are a community i just want to clarify some things :)

Comment: @MrLY I'm not in the least bit angry

Comment: *Acknowledgment* must be carefully distinguished from *endorsement*.

Answer (score 38):

There are also a bunch of hats referring to *popular culture* (e.g. Darth Vader, Never Ending Story). Being culturally *tolerant and accepting* does not mean that we pretend other cultures, which includes religions, don't exist. It means that we acknowledge their existence and accept them.

Stack Overflow has always been culturally open and not exclusionary. Starting a practice of not mentioning "other cultures" (be that movie references or religions), you're on a very slippery slope which leads nowhere good, because somebody is always going to be offended by whatever you say.

The holiday exists. It has been turned into a hat. You don't have to celebrate the holiday if you don't want to.

Answer (score 10):

There's also "I Have A Little Dreidel" - post or vote on any of the days of Chanukah. No emphasis of any particular religion is intended. If we've missed some that could make an interesting cultural references and could *in some way* be translated as a hat, feel free to mention them. But we also don't want *everything* to be about religious events - most of the themed hats are about generic cultural references.

You don't need to celebrate Epiphany to post of vote on January 6th.

Answer (score 4):

Well, while the epiphany is certainly Christian in origin, the [Befana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana#History), whom the hat is referred to is certainly a pagan figure and not a Christian one. It is a celebration of a Roman goddess which is still practiced in Italy.

> "This Befana appears to be heir at law of a certain heathen goddess called Strenia, who presided over the new-year's gifts, 'Strenae,' from which, indeed, she derived her name. Her presents were of the same description as those of the Befana—figs, dates, and honey. Moreover her solemnities were vigorously opposed by the early Christians on account of their noisy, riotous, and licentious character"

This is referenced multiple times in the hat. Don't stop at the name.

This is like complaining for awarding a tree shaped hat on December 25th. Sure, Christmas is a Christian holiday. The tree is not, though.

Comment: To be fair, this distinction doesn't really make the whole thing any less religious. At no point did OP complain that they don't want to celebrate this *Christian* holiday… :)

Comment: @deceze Are you saying that people filling their stockings with candy are roman polytheists? :-D

Comment: "Paganism", "Roman goddess"… there are enough people out there for whom that's enough to hang their hat on for a Holy War… ;)

Comment: Also Christmas is practically a parallel secular, capitalist holiday now, anyway.

Comment: @TylerH not everywhere, in the first world it is.

Comment: @Sklivvz Which is where our users overwhelmingly are, too, by virtue of their roles and the fact they have computers with internet connections.

Comment: @TylerH 40% of our traffic is from India alone :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz I consider India a first-world country. Their economy is larger than the United Kingdom, and their healthcare sector, tech sector, and industrial sector are all world class. India was also invited to join the NATO BMD (NATO membership was originally what constituted a country being "first world") over 5 years ago.